# Android: View.fitSystemWindows() not called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

When I switch from landscape to portrait mode, `View.fitSystemWindows()` is not called. Therefore my view becomes offset with no reason because the navigation bar is not at the same place as it used to be :-(. I tried calling `View.requestFitSystemWindows()` but that did not make anything. Any idea what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I workarounded that by calling `setPadding` manually

```
@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Not sure this is the nicest solution but it works for me...